# Concatenate with conditions

Tags: r

I'm trying to concatenate some rows of 1 file into 1 row, but it must depend on the content and is variable throughout the file.

Simplified version of my datafile:

```
>xy|number|Name
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABC
>xy|number2|Name2
ABCABCABC
ABCABC
>xy|number3|Name3
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABCAB
```

I want it to end in something like this: (space means different column)

```
xy number Name ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC
xy number2 Name2 ABCABCABCABCABC
xy number3 Name3 ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCAB
```

Comment: I'm sure that this could be done in R, but it is almost certainly the wrong language for the task (and what are you going to do with these structures in R?).  Consider an imperative language like Perl or C.

Comment: @MatthewLUndberg If he wants to do post-processing in R, and the file isn't gigantic, I don't see why R is the wrong language to do this.

Comment: Downvote for failing to describe the rule that governs the choice of rows. "Depends on content" is NOT a description!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a similar solution to @MatthewLundberg, but using `cumsum` to split the vector.

```
file<-scan('~/Desktop/data.txt','character')
h<-grepl('^>',file)
file[h]<-gsub('^>','',paste0(file[h],'|'),'')
l<-split(file,cumsum(h))
do.call(rbind,strsplit(sapply(l,paste,collapse=''),'[|]'))

#   [,1] [,2]      [,3]    [,4]                              
# 1 "xy" "number"  "Name"  "ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC"  
# 2 "xy" "number2" "Name2" "ABCABCABCABCABC"                 
# 3 "xy" "number3" "Name3" "ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCAB"
```

Comment: Ensure here, that `file` is not a factor.

Comment: I was just writing something similar but with the second and 4th lines unpacked...  no point in posting now... read the file with `scan`, `what = character()` and this will be a complete answer on it's own.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't give me 4 columns, it only gives me 2 (xy and then the rest), but I do have a lot to work with now, thank you!

Comment: @user1941884 That is very strange. I copied your test data exactly, and it works.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm being stupid today. Wrong input file. Works perfectly, thank you sooo much!!

Comment: First time I'm using this option to ask questions, and I'm really glad I did. Thank you thank you!

Comment: @user1941884 Welcome to SO. Click the check mark beside the answer if you consider this answer to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
dat <- read.table(file, header=FALSE)

h <- grep('^>', dat$V1)
m <- matrix(c(h, c(h[-1]-1, length(dat$V1))), ncol=2)
gsub('[|]', ' ', 
      sub('>', '',
        apply(m, 1, function(x)
          paste(dat$V1[x[1]], paste(dat$V1[(x[1]+1):x[2]], collapse=''))
             )
          )
     )
## [1] "xy number Name ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC"    
## [2] "xy number2 Name2 ABCABCABCABCABC"                 
## [3] "xy number3 Name3 ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCAB"
```

Comment: Somehow I lose the number and name here, but you gave me a lot of great information, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something for your consideration in case you want a data.frame with the result:

```
raw <- ">xy|number|Name
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABC
>xy|number2|Name2
ABCABCABC
ABCABC
>xy|number3|Name3
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABCABCABC
ABCAB"

s <- readLines(textConnection(raw))        # s is vector of strings

first.line <- which(substr(s,1,1) == ">")  # find first line of set
N <- length(first.line)
first.line <- c(first.line, length(s)+1)   # add first line past end

# Preallocate data.frame (good idea if large)
d <- data.frame(X1=rep("",N), X2=rep("",N), X3=rep("",N), X4=rep("",N),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:N)
{
  w <- unlist(strsplit(s[first.line[i]],">|\\|"))  # Parse 1st line
  d$X1[i] <- w[2]
  d$X2[i] <- w[3]
  d$X3[i] <- w[4]
  d$X4[i] <- paste(s[ (first.line[i]+1) : (first.line[i+1]-1) ], collapse="")
}


d
  X1      X2    X3                               X4
1 xy  number  Name   ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABC
2 xy number2 Name2                  ABCABCABCABCABC
3 xy number3 Name3 ABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCABCAB
```

I wish by default R left-justified strings when it displays them in a data.frame.